# Javascript call back function not called in flutter webview

Tags: flutter

I am trying to load an HTML form in a webview which has some callbacks on button clicks which I am trying to handle in javascript handler but are not getting invoked.

This is how I defined the webview.

```
webView = InAppWebView(
    initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(
      data: fileText
    ),
    onWebViewCreated: (controller) =>
    _controller = controller..addJavaScriptHandler(
        handlerName: 'AndroidInterface',
        callback: (data) {
          // Catch and handle js function
          print(data);
          for(var d in data){
            print(d);
          }
        },
      ),

    // _controller.evaluateJavascript(source: source)
  )
```

The html form is calling the function like.

```
AndroidInterface.saveFormData(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript Handler implementation is not correct.
To call a JavaScript Handler from js, you need to use:

```js
window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('HANDLER_NAME_HERE', arguments_here);
```

The handler name must match the one you defined in Dart/Flutter side using `controller.addJavaScriptHandler()`.

Check the online docs [JavaScript Communication](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/webview/javascript/communication#JavaScript-Handlers) for more details.

Here is a simple working example using the current latest `flutter_inappwebview` plugin version 6 ([6.0.0-beta.17](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/6.0.0-beta.17)):

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (!kIsWeb &&
      kDebugMode &&
      defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    await InAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(kDebugMode);
  }
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("InAppWebView test"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: InAppWebView(
              key: webViewKey,
              initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(data: """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <script>
    document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const result = {
        firstname: document.querySelector('#fname').value,
        lastname: document.querySelector('#lname').value
      };
      window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('saveFormData', result);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
"""),
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                webViewController = controller;

                controller.addJavaScriptHandler(
                    handlerName: 'saveFormData',
                    callback: (arguments) {
                      final Map<String, dynamic> formData = arguments[0];
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Text(jsonEncode(formData)),
                        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                      ));
                    });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

[image: InAppWebView example]